# How to check if the application has been minimized

Tags: qt, qt5

Whenever the application window is minimized or maximized i want to link that signal with a function.

This is the code.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    Renderer w(model ); // This is  QWidget
    w.show();
    QObject::connect(&w, &QWindow::windowStateChanged, [&](Qt::WindowState state) {
        });

        // how will i define the QObject::connect 
    return application.exec();
}
```

What would be the parameters for the QObject::connect function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve by using QApplication::focusWindow()

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    Renderer w; // This is  QWidget
    w.show();
    QObject::connect(QApplication::focusWindow(), &Renderer::stateChanged, [&](bool maximized) {
        qDebug() << "Maximized?" << maximized;
    });
    return application.exec();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is working and compiling code? `QApplication::focusWindow()` will return an `QWindow*` of which you can neither take an rvalue (using `&`) nor does a QWindow inherit `Renderer`.

Comment: connect function needs a QWIndow* which is what QApplication::focusWindow() gives.

Comment: `QApplication::focusWindow()`gives a Pointer, that is correct, but you take a reference to said pointer by adding the `&`. Also, QWindow does not inherit Renderer, so the window returned by `focusWindow()` won't provide `Renderer::stateChanged`. This looks very weird to me, but if you say it works I have to take your for for it - I tried your exact code and failed to compile with clang for the stated reasons though

Comment: @T3H40 typo error there should be no reference , i am correcting it in the code

Comment: Great, this will fix one issue. You are still left with QWindow not being a renderer. You can use your original design though, connecting to `&QWindow::windowStateChanged`. Be careful however, that focusWindow() is *not* your Renderer instance w. It is the generated QWindow that is the base of the currently focused view. While this will probably work for your purpose, you will run into issues if you try to access the sender of your changeSignal as a Renderer. Also, if the focusWindow changes (e.g. if you have multiple windows), your signal won't reconnect which might be confusing for others.

Comment: @T3 H40 Thanks for your comments , i am able to understand the issues i might face with current approach , but i have only one widow in the application and it works for my purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the `connect` function to connect to different slots based on the given value. You can however simply call the functions based on the value by checking the value in your lambda.

At least, you could if you had the signal. However, your connect suggests that `w` is - or inherits - a QWindow. You can obviously only connect to signals your class provides. As your Renderer is a QWidget, you have to check that class.

The [documentation of QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setWindowState) tells us, that there is no windowStateChanged signal, but it states:

> When the window state changes, the widget receives a changeEvent() of type QEvent::WindowStateChange.

So therefor we can create our own signal and connect to that. This can look similar to the following working example:

```
#ifndef RENDERER_H
#define RENDERER_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QEvent>

class Renderer : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void stateChanged(bool isMaximized);

protected:
    void changeEvent(QEvent *e)
    {
        if(e->type() == QEvent::WindowStateChange) {
            emit stateChanged(windowState() & ~Qt::WindowMaximized);
        }
        QWidget::changeEvent(e);
    }
};

#endif  // RENDERER_H
```

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    Renderer w; // This is  QWidget
    w.show();
    QObject::connect(&w, &Renderer::stateChanged, [&](bool maximized) {
        qDebug() << "Maximized?" << maximized;
    });
    return application.exec();
}
```

Comment: the code  does not compile as w is QWidget , even if i cast it to QWindow ,   QWindow *wndQT = (QWindow*)w.window();

Comment: And use it in Connect than the lambda does not execute.

Comment: @Summit I see. You imply the usage of a Window in your connect but use a QWidget for renderer. I updated my answer check it out :)

Comment: I'd recommend you to look into some basics, how casting works and what it is. You can only cast a variable to a type which the value actually does represent. Otherwise you run into problems. Think of it this way: Telling the computer that your lemon is an apple will let the computer _think_ its an apple, but it won't taste sweet because of that.